# Why am I getting an extra ] when I try to extract a git repo URL using Perl's substr?

Tags: perl

So I have some weird behavior from a rather simple snippet of code. I'm not quite sure why this is happening. It seems like these two snippets should do the same thing:

```
my $s = "some-package    [git://github.com/repo/some-package]";
$s = substr($s, 0, length($s)-1);
$s = substr($s, index($s, "[")+1);
print $s . "\n";
```

and

```
my $s = "some-package    [git://github.com/repo/some-package]";
$s = substr($s, index($s, "[")+1, length($s)-1);
print $s . "\n";
```

But these are the results I get, for each pieces of code:

```
git://github.com/repo/some-package

git://github.com/repo/some-package]
```

Not quite sure why the second snippet isn't removing the last character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) is a *length*, not an index. So, consider the string `'abcde'`. Index of `b` is `1`. You want to start at `c`, so the starting position is `2`. The length of the string is `5`. Subtract `1` from it to get `4`. Therefore,

```
$s = 'abcde';
substr($s, index($s, 'b') + 1, length($s) - 1);
```

translates to

```
substr($s, 2, 4)
```

what you need is

```
my $s = "some-package    [git://github.com/repo/some-package]";
my $i = index($s, '[') + 1;
say substr($s, $i, length($s) - $i - 1);
```

You can also use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) for this:

```
my $s = "some-package    [git://github.com/repo/some-package]";
say split(qr{ \S+ \s+ \[ | \] }x, $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second snippet you ask to give you too many characters: you start getting a substring from position `index($s, "[")+1` but ask to give you as many as `length($s)-1` characters (e.g. the length of all the `"some-package     [git://....]"` staff minus one).  You should take `length($s)-index($s, "[")-2` instead.

```
my $s = "some-package    [git://github.com/repo/some-package]";
$s = substr($s, index($s, "[")+1, length($s)-index($s, "[")-2);
print $s . "\n";
```

But actually you should just use regex for such tasks.

```
if ($s =~ m|\[(git://.*?)\]|) {
    my $repo = $1;
    print "$repo\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal place to use Perl's regular expressions.

You want to find the string that is in between the two brackets, right?  So here's what you do.

```
my $s = "some-package    [git://github.com/repo/some-package]";
if ( $s =~ /\[(.+)\]/ ) {
    my $repo = $1;
}
else {
    die "Couldn't find a string between two brackets";
}
```

There are many good regex tutorials available online to get you started.  Once you use regex for your string parsing, you'll wonder how you ever got by with index + substr.